Making sense of the chrome performance tab, low framerate, low cpu, low gpu

I'm looking for some help understanding chrome dev tools performance tab. In the screenshot I am profiling the performance of "bunnymark", a website for testing the performance of WebGL rendering engine Pixi.js. You click and hold to add thousands of sprites to the scene until performance suffers. I'm running on a 3060 at a refresh rate of 144Hz. After adding enough bunnies, the performance suffers. But when profiling the performance using Chrome dev tools, the CPU usage is still very small, and the GPU usage is equally small. So where would I go from here to find the cause? Why are frames being dropped?
I'm actually trying to improve render performance on a much larger project, and using bunnymark as a baseline test to understand dev tools profiler. But it doesn't seem to add up. All help greatly appreciated, thank you!

Windows task manager reports Chrome as using 100% GPU in this scenario, does this mean that the GPU row in the performance tab is the culprit and can't be relied on?
